# Graded readers for Hindi?

Tags: electronic-resources, physical-resources, graded-readers, hindi

[Extensive reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensive_reading) or reading for pleasure is an excellent way of getting a lot of "comprehensible input" in a foreign language. Graded readers provide this type of comprehensible input.

Hindi is one of the [biggest languages in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers) by number of native speakers. Hence this question: are there any graded readers for Hindi? And where can they be found?

---

**Update**: Since some answerers misinterpret the question: what I am looking for is a **graded reader for extensive reading**, i.e. a resource that allows you to acquire vocabulary by reading, not by looking up words or studying vocabulary lists that are provided with the text. A graded reader is not the same thing as a **reader for intensive reading**, in which texts are accompanied by vocabulary lists. Arranging the texts by order of difficulty does not turn a reader for intensive reading into a graded reader for extensive reading.

Answer (score 4):

For beginners, there is one called [Reading Hindi: Novice to Intermediate](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0367222574/ref=sw_img_1?smid=&psc=1) by Kusum Knapczyk & Peter Knapczyk. If you are at a more advanced level, there is also [The Routledge Intermediate Hindi Reader](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Routledge-Intermediate-Reader-Language-Readers/dp/0415601762/ref=tmm_pap_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1635093522&sr=1-1) by Naresh Sharma.

Comment: These aren't graded readers, unfortunately. It looks like you are confusing "reader" with "graded reader".

Comment: Both books describe themselves as [graded readers](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/graded-reader) in the first pages and both are written for learners of Hindi as a second language, organised in order of difficulty. They are not written for native Hindi speakers, which a reader (or an anthology) would be.

Comment: What is your understanding of a graded reader? Perhaps the conventions for usage of the term are not standardised.

Comment: Both books are readers that consist of lessons in which each text is accompanied with a glossary list. That is what makes these books "readers" as opposed to "graded readers", which don't consist of lesson but allow extensive reading. Please cite the sections from the introduction in which these books describe explicitly themselves as "graded readers".

Comment: It seems that we are using different definitions of readers versus graded readers, but regardless of that fact, I understand that my suggestions don't meet the requirements of what you are looking for. I don't have copies of these books, but if you go to "Look Inside" on Amazon, you will see on the first page after the title page in both cases that they are described as graded readers/readings.

Comment: I used the "Look inside" function and did not find any evidence that these books describe themselves as "graded readers". They use the term "reader" instead, and that distinction is essential to the question. A textbook is not a "graded reader".

Comment: I would add that a reader at beginner level would either not be very extensive or it would have a lot of help to get through it. If you don't want notes but you just want simple texts to read at that level, there are bilingual Hindi-English children's books, such as "Am I Small?"

Comment: It says on the first page of the latter suggestion: "_The Routledge Intermediate Hindi Reader_ has been specially designed for intermediate and advanced learners of Hindi and comprises a broad selection of graded readings." Then, on the next page, it says "Each reader contains approximately 20 readings graded in order of difficulty to allow the learner to grow with the book and to acquire the necessary skills to continue reading independently."

Comment: It says on the first page of the former suggestion: "_Reading Hindi: Novice to Intermediate_ is an innovative collection of graded readings... The graded readings support the learner as they build their confidence with the language, gradually encountering a wider range of grammar constructions and vocabulary as the book progresses."

Comment: That's the source of the confusion then. A reader with "graded readings" is not a graded reader. Graded readers or for extensive reading. The books you suggested are for intensive reading: you actually *study* vocabulary for these lessons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130815/discussion-between-jenny-and-tsundoku).

Answer (score 0):

There is a new series of books which you can find on Amazon, and on https://www.surbhimehra.com/ - similar to BOB books here in the US.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Could you please describe the books, possibly adding what level(s) they are aimed at and what sorts of texts they contain? In Stack Exchange, just providing a link is not sufficient for a good answer.